# I can't resolve .local hostnames on my android

Tags: android, dns

I have a raspberry pi as a local NAS server and I named it pinas.local

I can access my pinas webpage (http://pinas.local) from my Mac, Windows and Ipad, but not from my Android device (Huawei P9 Android 7.0)

If I do that I get a error message in Dutch but the last line says:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I changed my settings in wifi setting and changed DHCP to static and entered my local router ip adress in the DNS field.

But that doesn't solve anything.

My phone is not rooted BTW.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

I love Android but I found this very annoying that Android can't handle a very basic/simple thing as resolving a .local address.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution aside from static IP? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81717/pis-local-url-http-raspberrypi-local-not-working-with-android-devices

Comment: No I have not find a solution for this, I'm using static IP's
Bummer

Comment: Just curious, if you turn off data (4g or whatever) on your device and then go to the URL does it resolve? It does for me. Not particularly useful, but interesting I guess.

Comment: There is an outstanding Android issue for this.  Please stop by and "star" the issue to vote for it to be implemented.  https://issuetracker.google.com/140786115